# How can I turn a photo into individual mesh objects

Tags: mesh, image

I have a simple photo of city lights at night. How can I convert the lights into meshes that I can manipulate.

[image]

Comment: You could add the photo as a plane mesh. If you want to make the bright areas of the image light up, you could manipulate the material settings so that light colors have a slight emission with the ramp tool.

Comment: You can try using *blam* for reconstruction: https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, this is a tricky one. I've done something similar to this but it might be tricky to do without distorting the image. Here are the options that come to mind.

### Cutting up the Mesh Manually:

This is probably the most obvious and most tedious option. Import the image as a plane, and meticulously cut apart the mesh using the knife tool, Boolean operators, or whatever else you can think of. Then separate them into individual objects (p in editmode). The texture should remained mapped appropriately.

### Convert to SVG then import

This is what I would probably try first. When you import an SVG file in Blender, it imports the individual colors and segments separately. I know programs exist for converting a standard image to SVG (I can't recommend anything directly sorry) so try to find one and make an SVG version of your image then import that. It will import as a collection of curve objects.

### Objects first

This is a weird one.
 Make your camera the exact same aspect ratio as your image, then set you image as the camera background. Then, create a mesh and edit the mesh so that you have created separate linked sets of vertices floating behind the positions of the lights on the image. Example mesh consisting of individual sets of vertices, but within the same object:

[image]

Once you have created all of your individual cells, select everything and use the UV map *Projection From View* option to generate a UV map that maps the image as seen from your camera. Then apply to the image as a texture for your objects using this UV Map. 
Now, separate all the bits by selecting everything in Edit mode, hitting <kbd>P</kbd>, and selecting *By Loose Parts*. You should now have a bunch of individual objects all textured with appropriate bits of your image.

---

What are you trying to accomplish ultimately? If you want to create the illusion of a 3D scene you might want to look up some tutorials on camera mapping in Blender. [Here](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/camera-mapping-tutorial-v2/) is one from BlenderGuru.

Hope one of these works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that doesn't require outside software or conversion. In general, we'll use the fact that this is a high contrast grayscale image to displace the white bits, then cut them out from the rest of the image using a boolean modifier.

Step 1: Import your image as a plane (using the [Import Images as Planes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images) addon)

[image: Import]

Step 2: Subdivide your mesh using the Simple algorithm (subdivide without smoothing), 6 subdivision levels

[image: Subsurf]

Step 3: Go to edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), then UV unwrap your plain from top orthographic view (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> > <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> > <kbd>U</kbd> > Project from View (Bounds))

[image: UV]

Step 4: Add a displacement modifier and add the same image you imported as texture, set displacement mapping to UV

[image: Displacement]

Step 5: Add a plane, then add a boolean modifier to your displaced mesh. Set the boolean object to the new plane, boolean type Difference.

[image: Bool]

Step 6: Apply all modifiers, by order (from top to bottom). Delete the 2nd plane, flatten almost completely on Z in Edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd> > <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0.01</kbd>).

[image: Flat]

Step 7: In edit mode, select all (<kbd>A</kbd>), then separate by loose parts (<kbd>P</kbd> > By Loose Parts).

That's it! The different pieces are now each a new mesh.

[image: Split]

Comment: Very clever, I love it!

Comment: WOW, very cool, I'll give it a go and see what happens.  Good job.