# how to turn text from image plane into a model

Tags: modeling

I am taking a logo with a transparent background and either using the boolean modifier or the knife project to cut these letters out of the triangle stand. My problem is that I don't know how to turn the image into a model. I tried the solidify, and it's just a box. I need to somehow make the black letters from the image into a shape of its own.

[image]
[image]

Moonboots gave the answer and this is how it turned out.

[image]

Comment: This was close, but this didn't work at all. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42342/how-can-i-turn-a-photo-into-individual-mesh-objects/42358#42358

Comment: Try to "Trace image to Grease Pencil" and then convert that to Curve or Mesh? There will be some faffing to do with holes but this doesn't seem to have any.

Comment: convert your image into svg in an image editor like Inkscape, then import the svg and convert to mesh

Comment: @moonboots thank you again. You are really a lot of help with all my questions. that's worked just right and was easy to do.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52563/how-do-i-turn-my-png-image-into-a-mesh-object/52564#52564

Comment: You too late @DuarteFarrajotaRamos moonboots already answered it, so I'm not sure why you decided to provide the same answer.